# Where to obtain the WinHttp 5.1 redistributable?

Tags: windows-2000, winhttp

i'm trying to find the redistributable for [Microsoft WinHttp 5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx).

Some older Windows 2000 machines in the enterprise do not have it.

[Microsoft's website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384086(VS.85).aspx) says:

> **Redistribution**
>
> WinHTTP 5.1 is available only with Windows Server
>   2003, Windows XP with Service Pack 1
>   (SP1), and Windows 2000 Professional
>   with Service Pack 3 (SP3).

Is that the only method?

Answer (score 1):

Someone on MSDN [mentioned that they thought it came with IE6SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384276(VS.85).aspx)(scroll down for the comments).  However, you should be able to [extract the file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132913) from the [Win2k Service Pack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/2000/bb735341.aspx).

Having used 2000 for a few years, I can't recall a time when updating to SP3 or SP4 caused any issues; if anything, Microsoft got their service packs right and with each update things seemed to be "a little better", although that is a subjective measure and not a qualitative analysis.  If possible, I'd consider [updating to SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=1001aaf1-749f-49f4-8010-297bd6ca33a0) (and Update1 as well), given that the service packs have been out for a considerable time now.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get WinHTTP 5.1 installed on Windows XP without any service packs is to install [KB842773](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=B93356B1-BA43-480F-983D-EB19368F9047). This may also work on Windows 2000, but I have no way of testing this currently.